# If $g=(135)(24)$, how can we find some permutation $k$ such that $kgk^{-1}=(246)(13)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Unfortunately the worked solutions were not quite worked and just stated the answer, so I'm at a complete loss as to how I could approach the question.

> In $S_6$ if $g=(135)(24)$, find a permutation $k$ such that $kgk^{-1}=(246)(13)$

The answer provided was $k=(12)(34)(56)$.

I am guessing that I will need to express

$$g=(135)(24)(6)$$

and

$$(246)(13)=(246)(13)(5)$$

But that is as far as I can get.

Comment: Do you know what conjugating $g$ by $k$ does to $g$'s cycle decomposition?

Comment: I know that it produces another permutation with the same cycle type $3,2,1$, but that is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
kgk^{-1} & =k(135)(24)k^{-1}\\
& =k(135)\color{red}k^{-1} \, \color{\red}k(24)k^{-1}\\
& = (k(1) \,\, k(3) \, \, k(5)) \,\,\,\, (k(2) \,\, k(4))
\end{align*}
Where $k(i)$ means the image of $i$ under permutation $k$.

You want this to be
$$(k(1) \,\, k(3) \, \, k(5)) \,\,\,\, (k(2) \,\, k(4)) = (2 \,\, 4 \,\, 6) \,\,\, (1\,\, 3)$$

Thus $1 \xrightarrow{k} 2$, $3 \xrightarrow{k} 4$ and so on.