# Finding all permutations which permute with a certain one

Tags: permutations

I have found this topic here: [How to find all the permutations which commute with a certain one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147291/how-to-find-all-the-permutations-which-commute-with-a-certain-one), but I still could not understand it. Could anyone please explain how to think about doing it?

If I have (12)(34), working in the symmetric group 4 for instance, how would I find every possible permutation that permutes with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Look for conjugates of a permutation. A link that can help is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532745/if-g-13524-how-can-we-find-some-permutation-k-such-that-kgk-1-246/1532749#1532749 For your problem, you want $k(12)(34)k^{-1}=(12)(34)$.

Comment: I am not really sure about what "(k(1)k(3)k(5))(k(2)k(4))" is meaning and how would I use that. It's from the post you send.

Comment: You should work with the so useful decomposition of a parmutation into a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @BurLeXyOOnuTz if you read the answer carefully you will see $k(1)$ is the image of $1$ under the (permutation)  function $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You want all the permutations $k \in S_4$ such that
$$k(12)(34)k^{-1}=(12)(34).$$
Since
$$
k(12)(34)k^{-1}  =k(12)\color{red}k^{-1} \, \color{\red}k(34)k^{-1}
= (k(1) \,\, k(2)) \,\,\,\, (k(3) \,\, k(4))
$$
Where $k(i)$ means the image of $i$ under permutation $k$.

You want this to be
$$(k(1) \,\, k(2)) \,\,\,\, (k(3) \,\, k(4)) = (1 \,\, 2) \,\,\, (3\,\, 4)$$

So our permutation $k$ can be such that 
$$(k(1) \,\, k(2))=(1 \,\, 2) \quad \text{ and } \quad (k(3) \,\, k(4))=(3\,\, 4)$$
OR
$$(k(1) \,\, k(2))=(3 \,\, 4) \quad \text{ and } \quad (k(3) \,\, k(4))=(1\,\, 2)$$

From the first scenario, we get either $k(1)=1,k(2)=2,k(3)=3,k(4)=4$ (identity permutation) or $k(1)=1,k(2)=2,k(3)=4,k(4)=3$ (this refers to the permutation $(34)$) or.....

Hope you can take it from here.

---

**Added response:**

I am adding this to answer the question you have raised in your comment.

Observe from the **second scenario** I have mentioned in my answer above, we can have $k(1)=3, k(2)=4$ and  $k(3)=2, k(4)=1$. So ask yourself, what will be the cycle notation for this permutation?

we have ($1 \xrightarrow{k} 3 \xrightarrow{k} 2 \xrightarrow{k} 4 \xrightarrow{k} 1$) and this corresponds to $(1324)$.

Comment: I saw in the answers that (1324) is a permutation that satisfies commutativity too, but I don't understand how would you get that using this technique. Could you please explain how would you get (1324) please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @BurLeXyOOnuTz I have added some remarks to my answer, so please take a look.

Comment: excuse me I do not feel like I understand k. As a question, can k(1) be 2,3,4 then k(2)=1,3,4 then k(3)=1,2,4 and k(4)=1,2,3 and we are just rearranging these maps in all possible ways?